# Prove that if $r \ge 1$ is a real number, then $ r^2 > r $ and $\frac{1}{r^2} \le \frac{1}{r}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am having some difficulty constructing the proof for the second relation ($r \ge 1$ implies $\frac{1}{r^2} \le \frac{1}{r}$). My thought process is to do a proof by contradiction by assuming that $r\ge 1$ and $\frac{1}{r^2} > \frac{1}{r}$. Then I would choose the case $r=1$ to arrive at my contradiction. But I am not so sure how to prove that the multiplicative inverse of $1^2$ is $1$.

**For reference, here is my proof for the first part.**

Proof: (for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $r \ge 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $ r^2 > r $)

Case 1: ($r=1$) Multiply both sides by r: $$r \cdot r = 1 \cdot r$$ By multiplicative identity, $$\Rightarrow  r^2 = 1 \cdot r = r $$ Case 2: ($r>1$) It is true by definition of r that $r>0$. By definition of an ordered field (which $\mathbb{R}$ is), for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, if $a < b$ and $c > 0$, then $ac<bc$. Using this relation I choose $a=1, b=r,$ and $c=r$. Thus, $$1*r < r*r$$ and by multiplicative identity $1*a = a$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$. So, $$r<r^2$$

**Here is my attempt at a proof of the second part.**

Proof: (for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $r \ge 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $ \frac{1}{r^2} \le \frac{1}{r} $)

Assume that the opposite is true, that is $r \ge 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $ \frac{1}{r^2} > \frac{1}{r} $. Now I take the case of $r=1$, by definition of multiplicative inverse, $$r*(r^{-1}) = 1$$  $$\Rightarrow 1*(r^{-1})=1$$ By definition of multiplicative identity $1*a = a$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $$r^{-1} = 1$$ Now I examine $(r^2)^{-1}$, $$(r^2)^{-1}=(r^{-1})*(r^{-1})= 1*1 = 1$$ (By mult. identity). Thus, I have a contradiction that $(r^2)^{-1}=1=r^{-1}$ when it was assumed that $(r^2)^{-1}>r^{-1}$.

**The last line specifically is where I think I may have made an error**. Can I just decompose $(r^2)^{-1}$ into $(r^{-1})*(r^{-1})$ or is there some axiom or proof that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics stack exchange. To get $\dfrac1r\ge \dfrac 1{r^2}$, divide both sides of $r\ge 1$ by $r^2$ (which is positive, so the direction of the inequality does not change)

Comment: Branching off of @J.W.Tanner's comment, you'd just have to prove that $r \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{1}{r}$, i.e., that $r \cdot \frac{1}{r^2}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $r$. This is easy to see by multiplying it by $r$ and combining the $r\cdot r$ into $r^2$.

Comment: That is certainly a simpler way of proving it. Thanks for the additional comment @kccu, it wasn't clear to me when I first attempted the problem that it would be simple to prove $r \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{1}{r}$, but now I see that multiplying the relation by $r$ will arrive at the definition of the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question can be re-formulated like this: show that in the interval $[1;+\infty)$, the funcion $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ assumes lesser values than the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. The inequality to prove is $$\frac{1}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x}\quad, x\in [1;+\infty)$$ This is equivalent to proving that (multilpying both sides by $x^3$, which is positive) $$x^2 \geq x\, , x\in [1;+\infty)$$ which you have already done.